# How to use group by when using multiple built in function in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a query that will list the student(s) with the highest total course credit points. The result should also display the number of courses a student is enrolled for along with the highest total credit points.

My query is

```
SELECT 
COUNT(COUNT(COURSE.COURSE_NO)) AS "Number of courses", 
MAX(SUM(COURSE.CREDITS)) AS "Total Credits"
FROM 
STUDENT
JOIN ENROLLMENT 
ON ENROLLMENT.S_ID = STUDENT.S_ID
JOIN COURSE_SECTION
ON COURSE_SECTION.C_SEC_ID = ENROLLMENT.C_SEC_ID
JOIN COURSE
ON COURSE.COURSE_NO = COURSE_SECTION.COURSE_NO
GROUP BY STUDENT.S_ID;
```

and the result is:

```
Number of courses Total Credits
----------------- -------------
            6            21
```

which belongs to a particular student.

How do I display the student ID along with the result? When I put STUDENT.S_ID into the SELECT clause it fires an error 'not a single group function'.

Comment: Use a sub-query. One step aggregate functions per query level.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM (SELECT e.S_ID
             COUNT(*) as num_courses,
             SUM(c.CREDITS) AS total_credits,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(c.CREDITS)) as seqnum
      FROM ENROLLMENT e JOIN
           COURSE_SECTION cs
           ON cs.C_SEC_ID = e.C_SEC_ID JOIN
           COURSE c
           ON c.COURSE_NO = cs.COURSE_NO
      GROUP BY e.S_ID
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This returns *all* students with the maximum number of credits.  After all, there might be more than one such student.

Other notes:

- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- The table `STUDENTS` is not needed, because the student id is in `ENROLLMENT`.
- Use simple column aliases, so you don't have to escape the names.

Comment: You have "total_credits" listed twice in your inline view. Also, is your rank supposed to be ascending? I might be missing something here.

Comment: Gordon Linnoff I use oracle, also I tried running your query but it spits out errors.

Comment: @RyanThompson . . . I think the problem was a typo in the column aliases.